# Overloading square brackets while inheriting vector class in c++?

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

i want to inherit a class called arithmeticVector from stl vector class. My problem is with square brackets overaloading. here is the code:

```
    template<class type>
type& ArithmeticVector<type>::operator[](int index) const{

    if(this->size()<=index || index < 0){

        throw string("Size Error!");

    }else{

        return vector<type>::operator[](index);

    }

}
```

it gives error:

Binding of reference to type `int` to a value of type `const int` drops qualifiers.

in the line:

```
        return vector<type>::operator[](index);
```

how can i fix it?

Comment: For the third time today: standard containers are not meant to be (publicly) derived from :)

Comment: Inheriting from `std::vector` seems very popular today. Still, it isn't a very good idea.

Comment: You shouldn't perform a range check for `operator[]` but instead perform the check in the `at` member function as `std::vector` does.

Comment: @juanchopanza, Which teacher, which teacher...

Comment: You should prefer composition over inheritance in this case.

Comment: you are right but our instructor asks us to do it.

Comment: Actually in general you should prefer composition rather than inheritance.  Only use inheritance if you have a really good reason to do so.

Comment: Would your instructor not understand why you decided to abandon his instructions when you give him good reasons, why you chose to do as you did?

Comment: If your instructor tells you to use inheritance, then you could at least make it private inheritance and avoid most of the pitfalls.

Comment: "However, as already noted, you should only attempt to derive from a class that defines a virtual destructor.  STL contain classes do not provide virtual destructors; in fact, they have no virtual methods for you to override at all.  This is a clear indication that these classes were not meant to be inherited from." API Design for C++ by Martin Reddy, page 376.

Comment: Instructor: do this thing. I'm not going to tell you how to do it. Just ask SO. What is my job supposed to be again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should either drop the `const` or add a `const`:

```
template <class type>
const type& ArithmeticVector<type>::operator[](int index) const

template <class type>
type& ArithmeticVector<type>::operator[](int index)
```

Comment: My class just modifies the operators of std::vector, the values in vector is still kept in std::vector class object.

Comment: I am confused, what has your comment to do with my proposal. Either your function is a constant member function, in which case it should return a const reference or it is not.

Comment: @UfukAlpTopçu usually, you would provide both methods shown in this answer.

Comment: in dual const ++ and -- operators are failing because of read-only data. without consts it does not compile.

Comment: is there any way to do it in one method?

Comment: @UfukAlpTopçu no, not really. You can provide one of the two, but there is no way to mix them both.